# Setting JavaScript window.location

Tags: javascript, window.location

I'm currently setting the window.location.pathname property to redirect the user to a relative URL.  The new URL has parameters, so the line of JavaScript looks like this:

```
window.location.pathname = window.location.pathname.substring( 0, window.location.pathname.lastIndexOf( '/' ) + 1 ) + 'myPage.xhtml?u=' + selected_user.Username;
```

This is successful in Firefox, however Chrome encodes the question mark with '%3F' and the request subsequently fails.

I'm not sure if I'm using window.location properly.  Do I need to use properties of window.location such as pathname or href?  I've found that as soon as I set one property the location is reloaded, so for example, the search and pathname properties can't be set separately.  Can window.location be set directly?  I only need to set a relative URL with a parameter.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

`pathname` and many other properties of `location` and links reflect only *part* of the URL:

```
http:  //www.example.com/path/to/example.html?param1=2&param3=4#fragment
^protocol^hostname      ^pathname            ^search           ^hash
```

As you can see, the `?...` part of the URL is not part of the `pathname`; it makes no sense to write a value containing `?` to `location.pathname`, as that part of a URL cannot contain a question mark. Chrome is correcting your mistake by encoding the character to a sequence that means a literal question mark, which doesn't terminate `pathname`.

These properties are great for breaking a URL into their constituent parts for you to process, but you probably don't want to write to them in this case. Instead, write to `location.href`. This represents the whole URL, but it's perfectly fine to write a relative URL to it; this will be worked out relative to the current value, so there is in fact no need to read and split the `pathname` at all:

```
location.href= 'myPage.xhtml?u='+encodeURIComponent(selected_user.Username);
```

Note the URL-encoding. If a username can contain characters other than alphanumerics you will probably need this to stop those characters breaking the parameter. Always URL-encode arbitrary strings before putting them into part of a URL.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation.  I've changed my code to use the href property and also to call encodeURIComponent().

Comment: Please note that [for most cases](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6725890/window-location-host-vs-window-location-hostname-and-cross-browser-compatibility), you want to use `location.host` instead of `location.hostname`. In short, this is because your code at some point may run in a server on a port other than 80.

Comment: Note that in (rare) case when the source is an iframe, then it needs to do window.parent.location.....

Answer (score 17):

Try setting the `location.href` property instead of `window.location.pathname`.

Comment: just `window.location = ...` is enough

Comment: Assigning a value to `window.location` causes an error in TypeScript. I guess assigning to `window.location.href` is the better option.

Answer (score 8):

Using `window.location.href` is considered the safest way to *set* a URL. I think this *should* fix the encoding problem.

```
window.location.href = window.location.pathname.substring( 0, window.location.pathname.lastIndexOf( '/' ) + 1 ) + 'myPage.xhtml?u=' + selected_user.Username;
```

If that doesn't help, please show an example URL.

Answer (score 0):

ב"ה

In your case you can set the `location.search` property without having to know/reset/decode the entire URL.

```
location.search = 'u=' + selected_user
```

Or if you have a lot of parameters with lots of different kinds of characters

```
location.search = 
    new URLSearchParams({
       u: selected_user,
       otherThing: "hi this %#%##^ is a "+
          "Very •}€○♡●¡● complex string"

    });
```