# Rails 3.1: The new way to use 'respond_to ... format.js'  without the 'page' variable

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to update Ruby on Rails to the version ***3.1***. I followed the [Upgrading to Rails 3.1](http://railscasts.com/episodes/282-upgrading-to-rails-3-1) screencast and all seems to work except for statements as

```
format.js { render(:update) { |page| page.redirect_to @article } }
```

In many controllers I have code like the following:

```
def create
  ...

  respond_to do |format|
    format.js { render(:update) { |page| page.redirect_to @article } }
  end
end
```

In all above cases, when I try to submit related forms performing JS requests, I get the following error:

```
ActionView::MissingTemplate (Missing template articles/update, application/update with {:handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :coffee], :formats=>[:js, :html], :locale=>[:en, :en]}. Searched in:
  * "/<MY_PROJECT_PATH>/app/views"
):

app/controllers/articles_controller.rb:114:in `create'

Rendered /<...>/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/actionpack-3.1.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/missing_template.erb within rescues/layout (0.3ms)
```

I know that the problem was related to RJS templates because them are not more available in the 3.1 release. So, in order to run some JavaScript code, in my controller files I may\should\can insert some JavaScript code as made in the following example:

```
format.js { render :js => "alert('Hello Rails');" }
```

*BTW* : ...*but*, **is it recommended to use JavaScript code directly in a controller file?**

Considering the above code in the `create` controller action, I would like to redirect user to the `@article` path after a successful submission. I can do:

```
format.js { render :js => "window.location.replace('#{article_url(@article)}');" }
```

..but, **how can I do the same thing *by following* the "Ruby on Rails Way to do things"? How RoR 3.1 would handle these cases?**

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I'd go with:

```
render js: %(window.location.href='#{article_path @article}')
```

Or put something along the lines of this in your `application_controller.rb`:

```
def js_redirect_to(path)
  render js: %(window.location.href='#{path}') and return
end
```

Then in your controllers you can just call:

```
js_redirect_to(article_path @article)
```

*Note I just made this up - not tested :)*

Comment: Hi Mike - what do you do if you have to pass params? For me, any additional param's '?' gets converted to '%3F' and the redirect fails.

Comment: @sscirrus I have updated my answer to work with params. (I switched from using window.location.pathname to window.location.href). Reasoning explained very clearly at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3643041/setting-javascript-window-location

Answer (score 5):

Using javascript code directly in controller files is not recommended.

Instead or `.rjs`, you can use `.js.erb` files. They act in a similar manner, allowing access to instance variables and helper methods.

Comment: If you're using JS purely to redirect the user, you should the controller to do the redirect.

Comment: In my question the example I reported is "very simple" because I have only two cases in which the create controller action responds. When response cases are more (that is, the JavaScript sometime can redirect to the article path, some other time to another URL and so on...), how can I handle those "conditional" responses in the .js.erb file? P.S.: I am not sure, but I think it is not recommended to state class variables in controller files just to handle those situations. What do you advice about?

Comment: So the solution I proposed in the question was correct? Can you (or someone else) "confirm" that and make me a little bit more sure?

Comment: This is the right way to do it.  Set your variables in the action (e.g. @article) and then in the js.erb you can render it to the screen via Jquery, Prototype, etc...

Comment: @james_schorr - Maybe I was not clear. Running Ruby on Rails *3.1*, I would like to handle *redirections* on responding to JavaScript requests (I think, it should be made someway in the `format.js { ... }` statement or in a way that I would like to know...). **How can I do that?**

Comment: I haven't had need to do that, as I just render the partial or partials based on the variable.  You could in the controller do something like if …whatever your criteria is … redirect_to url_here else redirect_to another_url_here.  I like the partial approach better, though.