# window.location.pathname Chrome vs Mozilla

Tags: javascript, browser

I want to change pathname via function window.location.pathname. I have got this source code.

```
var hash = window.location.hash;
window.location.pathname = hash;
```

in Mozilla it works right, but in Chrome doesn't. Chrome write me this adress.

> /%23!stranka=novinky&cisloStranky=1&rubrika=novinky&clanek=783?stranka=kontakty#!stranka=novinky&cisloStranky=1&rubrika=novinky&clanek=783

Value of hash is `#!stranka=novinky&cisloStranky=1&rubrika=novinky&clanek=783`

Have someone any idea?

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3643041/setting-javascript-window-location

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to understand that `location.hash` includes the `#` itself as well. The rest of the `location.hash` is, per spec, URLencoded, but the `#` isn't.

*I said "per spec", as Firefox has a [bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=483304) related to the `location.hash` property.*

If you want to change `location.pathname` to the hash with the value included, you'll have to encode the `#` before doing so.

*Example:*

```
var hash=location.hash.substring(1)
location.pathname='%23'+hash
```

If you don't want the hash to be included, just use

```
var hash=location.hash.substring(1)
location.pathname=hash
```