# Django built-in tags encoding '?' to '%3F'

Tags: django, django-templates

I'm trying to do a pagination that passes in `?page={{ page_num }}` into the end of the url.

This is what I'm trying to do and this is what the output is:

```
        $('#prev-page').click(() => {
            window.location.pathname = "{% url 'xadmin:get_deposits' %}?page={{ page_no|add:'-1' }}"
        });
        $('#next-page').click(() => {
            window.location.pathname = "{% url 'xadmin:get_deposits' %}?page={{ page_no|add:'1' }}"
        });
```

Expected URL:
http://localhost:8000/xadmin/deposits/?page=1

Actual URL:
http://localhost:8000/xadmin/deposits/%3Fpage=1

Comment: If you check the source of your page, you can see that the front-end side (javascreipt) do that. Have you tried `encodeURI("{% url 'xadmin:get_deposits' %}?page={{ page_no|add:'1' }}")`? If this is not working, you can add supports to `utf-8` url handing in Django side.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
 $('#prev-page').click(() => {
    window.location = "?page={{ page_no|add:'-1' }}"
  });
 $('#next-page').click(() => {
    window.location = "?page={{ page_no|add:'1' }}"
 });
```

Comment: Any reason why `window.location.pathname` enforces the encoding but `window.location` doesnt?

Comment: Not sure, but according to this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3643041/setting-javascript-window-location may be the browser.

Comment: thanks. From reading that question, it looks like the correct answer is because pathname assumes that all values will be part of a `pathspec` in which case a `?` character would be assumed to translate literally as part of a path, and not as the `?` which is the delimiter that denotes the beginning of a querystring!